# Developing a simple Webpart with NAPA on SharePoint Online 2013 in o365 . jQuery?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, apps-development, office-365, office-365-develop-tool

Installed NAPA and playing around. Some high level questions.

1. If I'm building a webpart.. why does it insist on me having default.aspx?
2. I put some jquery in ClientWebPart.aspx page to cause a redirect, but when I deploy and add the webpart to a page on SPO it does nothing, and view source does not show my code, is this because its happening an iframe or something?
3. Can I add and access WebPart properties with NAPA alone (and no VS2012)?
4. If I can get JQuery working in my ClientWebpart.aspx page, can I access other objects likes Custom lists on pages where the webpart is added on prerender. Say I want to add a webpart that causes everything on the page to highlight a particular string.. possible with just a NAPA webpart?

Many Thanks.

Comment: To help you out but not answering all your questions; the AppPart (webpart in app / napa) will render in an Iframe on the page where it is used, there of some of the "problems" you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

1. SharePoint Apps can have three types of experiences Full, App Part (ClientWebPart) and Custom Action. The Full which is the one you get when clicking on the App is required and Napa implements this using Default.aspx (by default)
2. Your App part renders in an IFrame and can't redirect
3. Yes, for example see step 10 and 11 in [Twitter Feed Napa App - Client Web Part in SharePoint 2013](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Twitter-Feed-Napa-App-Client-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx)
4. No you'll not have access to anything on the page where the App Part is added. (You're in an IFrame)

Comment: 4. Note that although you don't have access to the page, you CAN get access to the calling (parent) web. So you can, for example, access a list in the parent.